# How to make italic TextView work in Eclipse graphic layout view? It even hangs up the PC

Tags: android, eclipse, fonts, textview, typeface

Working in Eclipse, I am trying to put some italics text onto a layout. The problem is, that when I am setting 
`android:textStyle="italic"`, the text disappears. (The height of content becomes 0 and the whole TextView becomes invisible.) Bold works OK. I have tried every typeface, but the result is the same.

On the device it shows itself in italics OK. But the layout is very complicated and its design without seeing it becomes very complicated, too.

Here is the TextView

```
     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/smallEpgNextProgramTime"
          android:layout_width="200dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:layout_margin="10dp"
          android:gravity="left|top"
          android:textSize="35dp"
          android:typeface="monospace"
          android:textStyle="italic"
          android:text="12:00-13:11"
    />
```

Android version is 2.3.3. Eclipse version is 2.6.

It is even worse. If I leave italics there, after some changes of layout view to graphics and back to text, Eclipse works slower and slower and hangs up the PC. So, I have to put it as "normal" in layout and to set textStyle by code. A bad bug it is!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think its an android platform issue.

Look at [Issue 22867: Incorrect layout preview when ITALIC text style used](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22867)

It doesn't show up on the layout's graphical representation but works correctly when you build and run the app.

**Update:**
If you want to preview for designing xml layout then just use

```
android:typeface="serif"
```

In this `android:textStyle="italic"` works. And text will displayed in italic style in graphical layout editor.

Its only works for this **serif typeface**.

Comment: So, I can only take it as it is?

Comment: Yes, because its work perfectly when you run your application. Its only problem on graphical layout representation with Android ADT.

Comment: It is even worse. If I leave italics there, after some changes of layout view to graphics and back to text, Eclipse works slower and slower and hangs up the PC. So, I have to put it as "normal" in layout and to set textStyle by code.

Comment: "It doesn't show up on the layout's graphical representation but works correctly when you build and run the app."

Until I change the typeface to serif, TextViews don't show up italic on my Galaxy Note 2 with Android 4.1.2. No idea why.

Answer (score 1):

```
 you can use this 

 TextView txtView;
 txtView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.smallEpgNextProgramTime);
 txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Restaurant <i><b>Hello</b></i>"));
```

Comment: No, I can't. because I am talking about how it looks in Eclipse viewer. Before any code takes place.

Answer (score 1):

What u wrote is 100% correct if you want to write in code you can use this..

```
            textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
            textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Hello do you want to show time in Italic. I recommend to show it as Digital view. If u r comfort then I'll share.

Comment: Please, reread the question. Application **works** OK. But I can't look at the layout in Eclipse layout viewer.

Comment: Sorry if something was wrong, Every Android developer has same problem in Eclipse layout viewer. As of now it is not yet solved.

Comment: It is even worse. If I leave italics there, after some changes of layout view to graphics and back to text, Eclipse works slower and slower and hangs up the PC. So, I have to put it as "normal" in layout and use your piece for change it by code.

Comment: Please give a try. It works fine for me digita italic and normal italic as well. Let me know if it is fine with you or not?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7802/discussion-between-gangnus-and-user11851)